# Entity Listener and caching for distributed system

Tags: database, spring, jakarta-ee, application-server, distributed-system

We have two application server.One is App server and other one is API server. Both have different caching system.If one change the DB other does not get known.Below is the Image for our architecture and we have used spring framework (Ehcache) for caching.[image]

We also have entity listener in our project. If one flow change the DB So other flow does not get affected.
How can we sync both Application Server and caching? Please help on this.

Comment: If both applications cache instances of exactly the same classes, you can simply cluster the EHCACHE instances.  Changes on one server will get reflected on the other.  You will have to make sure that both servers cache exactly the same entities so that none bypasses the cache to update the database directly.  You can achieve this by having the same EHCACHE configuration in both apps.

Comment: You may also consider taking all the cacheable entity classes and bundling them into a single JAR, along with the necessary cache configuration.  Then, all applications would use this single JAR.  In the future, if you add more app servers for your web app or for the API, the same caching configuration will continue to be used across all servers.  Another advantage this will offers is the flexibility to switch the cache implementation if required.

Comment: Thanks Manish for suggesting Ehcache clustering. We have made one entity listener in API server for web notification. if App server changes the entity then API(Web) server does not know. can we cluster spring configuration for both server or one configuration for both server.If yes, Could you please suggest how can we achieve this one.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The cluster configuration can be the same across machines if instances of the same class are being cached and same cache names are used.  Details on cluster configuration are available in the EHCACHE documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of a couple of approaches to do this.

**1. Cluster with replication:** If you want to go with the out of the box cache provider from Spring i.e Ehcache, it would essentially mean yours is a node level cache and would need replication. Check the following link for configuring ehcache cluster using Terracotta
http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.6/configuration/distributed-cache-configuration

**2. Centralized Cache server** My personal choice would be a centralized cache that would provide out of the box support for horizontal scaling with their own clustering if need be. This would involve removing caching from the node level and instead having it centralized on a cache server. So essentially your cache server sits between your DB and your application nodes. You could look at Memcached, Aerospike and Redis.

- Memcached seems to have a Spring integration
  https://code.google.com/p/simple-spring-memcached/
- Aerospike too has an integration available with Spring Data project called **spring-data-aerospike**